# Output value of keys in hash by method in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, dsl

I wrote weird, little and simple DSL on ruby, and I stuck on output values of keys.
I need to output values of concrete key of hash by that command:

```rb
p config.key1
#> Output down below:
#> "value1"
# here's key1 is key of hash, i want to output value of key that i wrote in method call.
# p config.key_name for example
```

There's my configus realisation:

```rb
require "deep_merge/rails_compat"

class Configus
  class InHash
    attr_reader :inner_hash

    def initialize
      @inner_hash = {}
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      if block_given?
        context = InHash.new
        context.instance_eval &block
        result = context.inner_hash
      else
        result = args
      end

      @inner_hash[name] = result
    end
  end

  def self.config(environment, parent = nil, &block)
    in_hash = InHash.new
    in_hash.instance_eval &block
    keys = in_hash.inner_hash.keys
    index = keys.find_index(environment)
    if parent && environment
      parent_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[parent]
      adopted_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
      merged_hash = parent_hash.deeper_merge!(adopted_hash, { :overwrite_arrays => "TRUE" })
    elsif environment == keys[index]
      "#{environment.capitalize} hash: " + in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my init.rb:

```rb
require "./configus"
require "pry"

config = Configus.config :staging, :production do
  production do
    key1 "value1"
    key2 "value2"
    group1 do
      key3 "value3"
      key4 "value4"
    end
  end

  staging do
    key2 "new value2"
    group1 do
      key4 "new value4"
    end
  end

  development do
    key1 "new value1"
    key2 "value2"
    group1 do
      key3 "new value3"
      key4 "value4"
    end
  end

  productionisgsgsd do
    key10 "value10"
  end
end

puts config.key1
#> I wrote output down below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
init.rb:35:in `<main>': undefined method `key1' for #<Hash:0x000056261379cdb0> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  key
               key?
               keys
```

I just want to output value of concrete key of hash with concrete command:
p config.key_name
But i don't know how to do that and because of my stupid problem i want to ask you guys.

P.S Sorry for my english skill and that weird realisation of dsl ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What is your current output/error? The first codeblock says `"value1"`, but I'm guessing that's the expected output, not the actual output, since you wouldn't be here if the output was correct.

Comment: I have production environment ok.

Than i have key1 with "value1" ok.

When i want to output it i want to do this with that command:

p config.key1

What i want to have in output:

"value1"

What i get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
init.rb:35:in `<main>': undefined method `key1' for #<Hash:0x0000564804424f08> (NoMethodError)

Comment: All i want is output value of key by config.key_name method
I just can't write my problem in other way :/
I have key1 "value1", and key1 is NOT method, that is key in HASH
But i want to output value of key by method, named like key_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you return a normal hash from your `Configus.config` method. Instead you should return your special `InHash` instance which you're able to customize behaviour.

The current issue lies here:

```
def self.config(environment, parent = nil, &block)
  in_hash = InHash.new
  in_hash.instance_eval &block
  keys = in_hash.inner_hash.keys
  index = keys.find_index(environment)
  if parent && environment
    parent_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[parent]
    adopted_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
    merged_hash = parent_hash.deeper_merge!(adopted_hash, { :overwrite_arrays => "TRUE" })
    # ^ the above line returns a normal hash from the method
    in_hash # <= add this to return your in_hash object
  elsif environment == keys[index]
    "#{environment.capitalize} hash: " + in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
  end
end
```

The problem is not entirely solved with the above, since this now returns your `InHash` instance, but your `InHash` has no way of fetching keys, you can only set them. So you want to add a way to fetch values:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if block_given?
    context = InHash.new
    context.instance_eval &block
    @inner_hash[name] = context # set to the nested InHash instance
  elsif args.empty?
    @inner_hash[name] # without arguments given read the value
  else
    @inner_hash[name] = args # set to the arguments provided
  end
end
```

The following code:

```
config = Configus.config :staging, :production do
  # ...
end
```

Should now set `config` to an `InHash` instance, that has your custom behaviour defined. The `args.empty?` check in `method_missing` will return a value if no further arguments are given. Meaning that:

```
config.key1
```

Should now return your `["value1"]` value. `@inner_hash[name] = args` will always set the value to an array. If you don't want this you might want to change it to:

```
@inner_hash[name] = args.size > 1 ? args : args.first
```

Comment: **note:** Normally when defining `method_missing` you also want to define `respond_to_missing?`, but I'm not going into depth, since that's a topic on its own. Checkout http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/15/methodmissing-politely/ for more info.